Is there any means of converting a blob file saved in MySQL database back to PDF
I have a python program that writes a file, then convert the file into a pdf. the pdf file will be  converted to blob file so that it can be stored into MySQL database.
I then want to view information saved into database so I use a treeview to display database contents, The PDF is showing as string of characters not readable, I guess that it's a blob format.
How to decode the file back to pdf so that it can be readable again?
def export_job():
    indexing=jobsTable.focus()
    content=jobsTable.item(indexing)
    listdata = content['values']
    file_name = listdata[4]
    print(file_name)`

Output:
b'%PDF-1.3\n3 0 obj\n<</Type /Page\n/Parent 1 0 R\n/Resources 2 0 R\n/Contents 4 0   R>>\nendobj\n4 0 obj\n<</Filter /FlateDecode /Length  398>>\nstream\nx\x9c\xbdTMO\xdc0\x10=\xb3\xbfb\x8e\xf4\xb0\xc3\xf8;\xce\rZ\xaaBU$D\xfa\x03\xbc\x89\x11)$i7\x8e\x10\xff\x1e\xdb\xbb\x825\xdak\xb1\xe4\x8b\xe7\xcd{o>\x12\x0e\xd7+Be\xe0yu\xd1\xc0\xd9w\x06\x8c#\x114\xf7p\xd9\xa4\'\xae\r\x1a\x0b\xc6*4\x06\x9a\x0eN\xbf\xb9\xe0k \t\x9do\x81\x8b\xd5\x17h\xfe\xec\xc1LKd\x1cL\xcc\x91<\x83o\xdc\x10\xc1w\xc1\xb5\xfe\xe5d}pN\xbeNc|\rp\xb3\x0c\x1b\xbf\xadA)\xb5\xde\xdf\x82RE\xfd\n\x8c\xb0H;\xfd\xa6o\x1f\xfd{\x1e#F\xbc\xa4>o\xdbi\x19\xdf!spD\xec\x90\x95s\x89\x15\x03\xc3\x08\x8d\xc8\xac?\x7f\xd5\xc0\x15R\xc9\xd4\xf8\xf6a\xae\xe1\xb1\x1f\xa7\xb1\xc8\'\x8d\xd2\x80\xae8\x8aj\xefj\xf0\xd0\x8f\xc9\x0f}$I\xa1i\t1\x16\x83\x874"\xea3\x05ZI\xa4\x9d\x8d\xa2t\xaeQ\x08\xd0\xd1\x96\xb69\xba\xfe\x8f\xa7(OQ\x9a\xa3\xb2\x06\x85\xcc\xca\xd7\xd3\x06\xae\xc6\xfbi;\xb8\xd0O\xb1\xcc~\x8c]}z:\xe2Wi\x9b7\xe83\xfd\xa6\xbd\x8b\xca\x92P\xab\xac|\xf9o\xe9\xff\x0e>.\xc1\xef\xd9wuY\x9cN\x1b\xad\xe2\xa2\x8b\x9d\xcd\x1fn\xdb=\xbb\xad\x87\x1an\x177\x86>\xbc\x14\t\xb6J\xc3\x96\x95@\xabs\x82\x8bHv\x0c\xa2\xe2\xa8X\x86l"D\x1c\xe9\x8e\xe4\x06\xb9\xfe\xdc\xeeX\x9e\x96]D\x8fv\xffUN\xc1\xcfES\x04Q*@\x98\xfc3H\x989t\xf0\x86x\x05\x94\xdb\xe9\xdc\nendstream\nendobj\n1 0 obj\n<</Type /Pages\n/Kids [3 0 R ]\n/Count 1\n/MediaBox [0 0 595.28 841.89]\n>>\nendobj\n5 0 obj\n<</Type /Font\n/BaseFont /Helvetica\n/Subtype /Type1\n/Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding\n>>\nendobj\n2 0 obj\n<<\n/ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]\n/Font <<\n/F1 5 0 R\n>>\n/XObject <<\n>>\n>>\nendobj\n6 0 obj\n<<\n/Producer (PyFPDF 1.7.2 http://pyfpdf.googlecode.com/)\n/CreationDate (D:20231204214847)\n>>\nendobj\n7 0 obj\n<<\n/Type /Catalog\n/Pages 1 0 R\n/OpenAction [3 0 R /FitH null]\n/PageLayout /OneColumn\n>>\nendobj\nxref\n0 8\n0000000000 65535 f \n0000000555 00000 n \n0000000738 00000 n \n0000000009 00000 n \n0000000087 00000 n \n0000000642 00000 n \n0000000842 00000 n \n0000000951 00000 n \ntrailer\n<<\n/Size 8\n/Root 7 0 R\n/Info 6 0 R\n>>\nstartxref\n1054\n%%EOF\n'

This is the code that retrieves the PDF data from the treeview named jobstable.
I print the contents on the console to see what is being printed  the that output is what I can   get

"so I use a treeview to display database contents" -> does the treeview (what is it? A tkinter widget?) know how to render a PDF?
